# Converting Each Value in static HashMap to String Java

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have got some troubles converting each value in my HashMap to a String.

```
    private static HashMap<String, List<Music>> musiksammlung = new 
    HashMap<String, List<Music>>();
```

This is my constructor for the HashMap. The key represents the album, the value a list of tracks from this album.
Now I want to convert each Music object to a String without creating a new HashMap, is this
possible? 
I've tried it with the Iterator scheme, for loop over the entry set and so on but nothing seems to work.

Edit://

My code for the convertmethod:

```
    public HashMap<String, List<String>> generateFormatList() {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> formatList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); 

    for(String key : musiksammlung.keySet())
            formatList.put(key, musiksammlung.get(key).toString());  
    return musiksammlung; 

}
```

But this always results in an error "is not applicable for the Arguments (String, String) so I have no idea. Do I have to override toString()?

Comment: you should post your code of what you've tried and what about it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path but you need to convert the existing `List<Music>` to a `List<String>` and put the `List<String>` into your new `HashMap`.

You also then want to return your newly created `HashMap<String, List<String>>` instead of your original one.

```
public HashMap<String, List<String>> generateFormatList() {
   HashMap<String, List<String>> formatList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); 

   for(String key : musiksammlung.keySet()) {
      // Value to store in map
      List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

      // Get the List<Music>
      List<Music> musicList = musiksammlung.get(key);
      for (Music m: musicList) {
          // Add String of each Music object to the List
          value.add(m.toString);
      }

      // Add the value to your new map
      formatList.put(key, value);  
   }
   // Return the new map
   return formatList;
}
```

So answer your question:

> Now I want to convert each Music object to a String without creating a
>   new HashMap, is this possible?

You need to create a new `HashMap`, because it's storing different type of value: `List<Music>` is different from `List<String>`.

Also as mentioned in my previous answer, make sure you override `Music.toString()` so that it returns a meaningful `String` for you instead of the one it inherits from its parent classes, which includes at least `java.lang.Object`

Comment: @teekay glad we could all help. As you're a new user, I'd like to let you know that you should mark a correct answer so it can help users who have the similar questions and help keep up the quality of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `HashMap` like this:

```
private static HashMap<String, List<Object>> musiksammlung = new HashMap<String,List<Object>>();
```

So you can save any kind of objects in this `HashMap`. Also use `instanceof` to check the type of the object before using it.

Answer (score 0):

`formatList` wants a `List<String>`, but `musiksammlung.get(key).toString()` returns a `String` (not a `List<String>`).  Did you mean this?

```
HashMap<String, String> formatList = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
Iterator<String> it = musiksammlung.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    List<Music> ml = musiksammlung.get(it.next());
    for (Music m : ml)
        System.out.println(m.toString());
}
```

And of course you should override the Music#toString() method with something you could use.